# Using select2 with ajax call to asp.Net service custom params

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-select2

I am tying to use select2 jQuery plugin and wanted to use AutoComplete from ajax call to an aspx.net WebMethod

My problem is how to get the term to search in my ajax call. I have tried this and it works.
JavaScript code:

```js
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
            ajax: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Code/Services/Dashboard/DashboardService.asmx/AccessRemoteData?",
                dataFilter: function(data) {
                    var msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
                    if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                        return msg.d;
                    else
                        return msg;
                },
                data:  { p_Term: 'd', p_Operator: 'StartsWith', p_LayoutName: layoutName } ,
                processResults: function (data) {
                         return {
                            results: data.items,
                            };
                        },
                        delay: 250,
                error: function() {
                    HideWaitMe();
                    alert("An error occurred");
                }
            }
    });
```

WebMethod code:

```vb
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False, XmlSerializeString:=False)>
    Public Function AccessRemoteData(p_Term As String, p_Operator As String, p_LayoutName As String) As String
        
        Dim serialiser As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim listNode As Items
        Try
            Dim tableKey As Long = m_SqlCo.GetLayout(p_LayoutName).TableKey
            listNode = m_DashboardManager.SearchRlinkNames(p_Operator, tableKey, p_Term)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim msg As New TError(Nothing, "Error", TSz.MsgLevelEnum.ErrorLevel, TSz.MsgTypeEnum.OtherType, "SearchService.SearchInFieldStatistics " & "An error occured while loading species", True)
            WriteLog(msg)
            'response.Success = False
            SessionStateManager.TitleMessage = "Error"
            SessionStateManager.InfoMessage = String.Format("An error occurred while loading list of names. Message:{0}", ex.Message)
            'response.Url = "BioloMicsInfo.aspx"
            SessionStateManager.GoToLoginPage = False
            Return serialiser.Serialize(False)
        End Try

        Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listNode)

    End Function
```

And it works but my problem is when I want to use the same as in the documentation:

```js
data: function (params) {
    var aa = {
        //term: params.term
        p_Term: params.term, // search term
        p_Operator: 'StartsWith',
        p_LayoutName: layoutName
    };
    return aa;
},
```

I have an error in the request

> exception: `System.ArgumentException`
>
> message:`Primitive JSON non valide : p_Operator.`
>
> stackstrace:`  à System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
>
> à System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
>
> à System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
>
> à System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
>
> à System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
>
> à System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
>
> à System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)
>
> à System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)`

Can you help me please to resolve my problem? Because I don't know how to get the input string to pass it to my service to return data.

Comment: added json.stringify to data element it works without any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to explain it but when I have changed it to

```
data: function (params) {
                            var aa = {
                                //term: params.term
                                p_Term: params.term, // search term
                                p_Operator: 'StartsWith',
                                p_LayoutName: layoutName
                            };
                            return JSON.stringify(aa);
                            },
```

so added json.stringify it works without any problem with adding

```
minimumInputLength: 1
```